# Java Poker Game Program

Tags: java

I'm working on this poker game project and I'm stuck on how to print out the card types and the default "sorry, you lost" at the end of the function. I'm not sure if my code is correct, I would appreciate any type of help.

Basically, my program needs to print out:

```
       [A Spades, 10 Spades, Q Spades, J Spades, K Spades] 
       Royal Flush!
         --------------------------------------------------

        [9 Spades, 10 Spades, Q Spades, J Spades, K Spades]
         Straight Flush!
         --------------------------------------------------
```

etc...

but my program only prints out:

```
          [A Spades, 10 Spades, Q Spades, J Spades, K Spades]
```

I'm having trouble printing the type (Royal Flush part).

```
/**
 * Check current currentHand using multipliers and goodHandTypes arrays Must
 * print yourHandType (default is "Sorry, you lost") at the end of function.
 * This can be checked by testCheckHands() and main() method.
 */
private void checkHands() {
    // implement this method!
  List<Card> sortedHand = new ArrayList<Card>(currentHand);
  Collections.sort(sortedHand, new Comparator<Card>() {

@Override

public int compare(Card card1, Card card2) {
    int rank1 = card1.getRank();
    int rank2 = card2.getRank();

    if (rank1 > rank2) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (rank1 < rank2){
        return -1;
    }



    return 0;
}

  }


    int rank = 0;
    String ranks;

    if (isRoyalPair() == true) {
        rank = 1;
     if (isTwoPair() == true) {
        rank = 2;
    }
    if (isThreeOfAKind() == true) {
        rank = 3;
    }

    if (isStraight() == true) {
        rank = 4;
    }
    if (isFlush() == true) {
        rank = 5;
    }
    if (isFullHouse() == true) {
        rank = 6;
    }
    if (isFourOfAKind() == true) {
        rank = 7;
    }
    if (isStraightFlush() == true) {
        rank = 8;
    }
    if (isRoyalFlush() == true) {
        rank = 9;
    }
    }

    rank -= 1;
    if (rank < 0) {
        ranks = "Sorry, you lost!";

    } else {
        ranks = goodHandTypes[rank];
    }

    System.out.println("" + ranks);



    switch (ranks) {
       case "1":
            this.balance += (this.bet * multipliers[0]);
            break;
        case "2":
           this.balance += (this.bet * multipliers[1]);
            break;
        case "3":
           this.balance += (this.bet * multipliers[2]);
            break;
       case "4":
           this.balance += (this.bet * multipliers[3]);
            break;
        case "5":
           this.balance += (this.bet * multipliers[4]);
            break;
        case "6":
            this.balance += (this.bet * multipliers[5]);
           break;
        case "7":
            this.balance += (this.bet * multipliers[6]);
           break;
        case "8":
            this.balance += (this.bet * multipliers[7]);
            break;
        case "9":
            this.balance += (this.bet * multipliers[8]);
            break;
        default:
            break;


            }
          }
```

and I already have all my methods for them, I just need help in finding a way to print them:

```
    private boolean isStraight() {

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCards; i++) {

        if (currentHand.get(i).getRank() != currentHand.get(i + 1).getRank()) {

            return false;

        }

    }

    return true;

}

private boolean isFlush() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCards; i++) {
        if (currentHand.get(i).getSuit() != currentHand.get(i + 1).getSuit()) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    return true;
}

private boolean isStraightFlush() {
    if (isStraight() == true && isFlush() == true) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isRoyalFlush() {
    if (isFlush() == false || isStraight() == false) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (currentHand.get(0).getRank() == 10) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}

private boolean isFourOfAKind() {

    //runs thru the hand for exactly 4 matches

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCards - 1; i++) {

        int counter = 0;

        for (int y = i + 1; y < numberOfCards; y++) {

            if (currentHand.get(i).getRank() == currentHand.get(0).getRank()) {

                counter++;
            }

        }

        if (counter == 4) {

            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isFullHouse() {
    if (isThreeOfAKind() == true && isOnePair() == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean isThreeOfAKind() {


    //matches three

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCards; i++) {

        int counter = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < numberOfCards; y++) {

            if (currentHand.get(i).getRank() == currentHand.get(y).getRank()) {

                counter++;

                for (int x = 0; x < numberOfCards; x++) {

                    if (currentHand.get(i).getRank() == currentHand.get(x).getRank()) {

                        counter++;
                    }
                }


                if (counter == 3) {
                    return true;


                } else {


                    return false;





                }
            }



private boolean isTwoPair() {
    //check if it is four of a kind or two pair))
    if (isFourOfAKind() == true) {
        return false;
    }
    int numberOfPair = 0;
    int counter = 1;

    return false;
}

private boolean isOnePair() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isRoyalPair() {

    if (isOnePair() == false && isTwoPair() == false && isThreeOfAKind() == false && isFourOfAKind() == false
            && isFullHouse() == false && isRoyalFlush() == false && isFlush() == false && isStraight() == false && isStraightFlush() == false) {

        return true;
    }



    return false;
}
```

Comment: Consider improving on your question, telling us how your program is supposed to work, how your code specifically is supposed to work -- walk us through it, what it's not doing correct,... etc...

Comment: I'm sorry for not explaining thoroughly. Basically I have to print out the card types for my poker game. So for example," [A Spades, 10 Spades, Q Spades, J Spades, K Spades] Royal Flush! " but my program only prints out the [A Spades, 10 Spades, Q Spades, J Spades, K Spades] part. I don't know how to print out the Royal Flush part... Does that make sense? I'm not sure how to explain it

Comment: Where are you trying to print out the `Royal Flush` part?

Comment: So your issue relates to the printing part of your program...how about showing us the printing part of the code?

Comment: I'm starting to believe this code shouldn't compile (the part with the anonymous Comparator). Try giving a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `checkHands()` was not called!

Wait...

```
 Collections.sort(sortedHand, new Comparator<Card>() {

@Override

public int compare(Card card1, Card card2) {
int rank1 = card1.getRank();
int rank2 = card2.getRank();

if (rank1 > rank2) {
    return 1;
}

if (rank1 < rank2){
    return -1;
}



return 0;
}

  }   /* Should be  );  here */ 


int rank = 0;
...
```

Less important

```
if (isRoyalPair() == true) {
    rank = 1;
 if (isTwoPair() == true) {
    rank = 2;
}
...
```

Hands (set of 5 cards) should not have a rank, (at least not if you are calling the number of each card it's rank). Hands should have a name, or rather a `String` for the best hand those cards make. So for example,

```
String type = "none";
...
if (isRoyalFlush()) type = "Royal Flush!!!!!";
//or   if(isRoyalFlush()) type = goodHandTypes[9];
```

Notice it's not necessary to compare what it's checking is `true` to `true`. There are a few ways you might implement the logic for readability and/or less typing and other concerns, but 9 `if` statements in that order is reasonable. And they only execute one statement each, so you can do without brackets.